# Why do we always type cast in Android/Java?

Tags: java, android

I am writing an Android app and just was curious about why we must always type-cast in Android. I understand that we need to be sure of the type so that our code runs properly, but is there, perhaps, another reason?

**Example**:

```
public class Navigation extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // other irrelevant code
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

In the context of this question, I am asking why we must type-cast the returned value of the findViewById. (I'm also curious how this type casting is done if one could explain that.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`findViewById` loads resources from a file. It returns some kind of `View`, but the Java compiler has no way of knowing that it will be a `DrawerLayout` (because it is defined in a file outside of Java's compilation).

If you need it to be a `DrawerLayout` in your code, you have to cast it.
That makes sure (at runtime) that it really is such an object (if it is not, you will get a `ClassCastException` and your program will abort at that point).

The reason you want to cast it as `DrawerLayout` is that you may want to call methods on the instance that are defined in that class. Sometimes, you may be fine with just the signature of the more general superclass. Then you don't have to cast it.

To be sure, the instance returned by `findViewById` is a `DrawerLayout` no matter if you cast it or not. But if you don't cast it, then Java won't let you treat it as a `DrawerLayout`. That is the point of a type-safe language: Unless the compiler can be sure that an object is of a certain class, it won't let you call methods (or access fields) for that class.

Answer (score 2):

`DrawerLayout` is a subclass of `View`.  A `DrawerLayout` object automatically has all the methods that a `View` has, but defines some methods of its own that are specific to `DrawerLayout`s.  If you don't cast it, you can't use any of those `DrawerLayout` methods; you can only use the methods defined for all `View`s.

The type-casting doesn't do anything, really.  `findViewById` is declared to return a `View`, since it can return all different kinds of `View`s.  But in reality, it will often return an object of some other class, that is a subclass of `View`.  The type-cast just checks to make sure that the returned object is really an instance of `DrawerLayout` (or one of its subclasses); if not, an exception is thrown, but if it is, you can now look at the object as a `DrawerLayout` and use the `DrawerLayout` methods.

Comment: Oh, so it's like an extension with the type cast?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: I was just corroborating what you had said: "object automatically has all the methods that a View has, but defines some methods of its own that are specific to DrawerLayouts" so by casting, the object is given all the methods of DrawerLayouts as well, rather than just of the View class.

Comment: Then I guess you're close.  But note that the type casting doesn't change the actual object at all; it just changes the compiler's view of it.  If you said `private View mDrawerLayout`, the compiler wouldn't know, at compile time, that `mDrawerLayout` is actually a `DrawerLayout`, and thus it won't allow you to use the methods.  If you said `private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout` and tried to assign it without the cast, the compiler would not let you do it; this is a language design decision mostly to prevent programmers writing buggy code by accident.

Answer (score -1):

In android - while writing java code you need to bring XML code inside Java.

So we use `R.id.drawer_layout` is what we want to bring inside java which becomes
`findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)` which returns an `Object`.

So we then assign it to a variable declared at top.

```
 private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
```

where `DrawerLayout` is a class in java android.

```
mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

Since `findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)` returns an object and we are assigning it to a variable we need to typecast by using

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

Comment: I recommend that you format your answer with the code indented to show up as code. It would make the answer easier to read.

Comment: This does not explain why you have to cast it; or at least, "Since ... returns an object and ... assigning it to a variable" is not an explanation of why you have to cast.