# casting 'findViewByld(...)' to 'EditText' is redundant

Tags: java, android

In the line `txtPass=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPass);` it says casting 'findViewByld(...)' to 'EditText' is redundant. How do I fix this?

````
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;


public class datainsert extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText txtPass, txtName, txtNum, txtEmail;
Button btnLogin, btnSignUp;
DatabaseReference reff;
Member member;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signup);
        txtPass=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPass);
        txtName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        txtNum=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNum);
        txtEmail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        btnLogin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnSignUp=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);
        reff= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Member");
        member=new Member();
        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Float agea=Float.parseFloat(txtPass.getText().toString().trim());
                Float hit= Float.parseFloat(txtName.getText().toString().trim());
                Float dsa= Float.parseFloat(txtEmail.getText().toString().trim());
                Long phn=Long.parseLong(txtNum.getText().toString().trim());


                member.setName(txtName.getText().toString().trim());
                member.setEmail(txtEmail.getText().toString().trim());
                member.setHt(dsa);
                member.setHm(hit);
                member.setPh(phn);
                member.setHt(agea);
                reff.push().setValue(member);
                Toast.makeText(datainsert.this,"data inserted sucessfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            });
    }
}```
````

Comment: Remove the casting: `txtPass=findViewById(R.id.txtPass);`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the cast to remove the warning:

```
txtPass = findViewById(R.id.txtPass);
```

Java figured out what you wanted from `findViewById`, so there's no need to cast it.  The message is not really an error (the existing code will compile and run just fine), so there's no harm in leaving it in.  It's considered better style to remove redundancies.

Comment: worth adding also that this isn't actually an error

Answer (score 0):

Replace these lines

```
    txtPass=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPass);
    txtName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    txtNum=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNum);
    txtEmail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
```

with these

```
    txtPass=findViewById(R.id.txtPass);
    txtName=findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    txtNum=findViewById(R.id.txtNum);
    txtEmail=findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
```

Both the View Type and actual view are same i.e EditText so typecasting is not required in this case you can directly assign the values

To more know about TypeCasting Check this 
[Why do we always type cast in Android/Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30430138/why-do-we-always-type-cast-in-android-java)