# Cannot resolve 'setEnabled' method. Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am pretty new to android studio. So I apologize for the newbie kind of question.  I have been reading posts on how to use the setEnabled(); method to enable and disable a bottom. As you will be able to see in the code, I am trying to enable a previously disabled button (through xml using `android:enabled="false"/>`) Whenever one of the Radiobuttons in a radioGroup is selected.

The 'setEnabled' part of the code gets highlighted in red and errors pop: cannot resolve method '`setEnabled(boolean)`'

Here is the code. I'd like to know why this is not working and how to fix it, rather than just the answer itself.
Thank you in advance

```
    public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radioButtonYes:
            if (checked)
                R.id.buttonNEXT.setEnabled(true);
            break;
        case R.id.radioButtonNo:
            if (checked)
                R.id.buttonNEXT.setEnabled(true);
                break;
        case R.id.radioButtonDontknow:
            if (checked)
                R.id.buttonNEXT.setEnabled(true);
                break;
    }
```

Comment: `R.id.buttonNEXT` is of `int` type, you can't use `setEnabled()` for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to use `setEnabled()` with an `int`, which is not possible as `R.id.someId` is of `int` type. Better to find a view for that id and then use `setEnabled()`.

This will work fine,

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNEXT)).setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! I fixed it and it works fine, and now i get what I was doing wrong. I am planning to send the response of either yes/no/dont know to a database, that is why I built the switch-case. Do you think that is efficient?

Comment: since you are enabling the same button in all three cases, i think there is no need to put `switch-case` unless you have only these three radioButtons.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't**

```
R.id.buttonNEXT.setEnabled(true);
```

**DO**

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNEXT)).setEnabled(true);
```

**Finally**:

```
switch(view.getId()) {
    case R.id.radioButtonYes:
        if (checked)
            ((Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNEXT)).setEnabled(true); 
            break;
```

Comment: tell him how would you get button object, thats what his problem is

Comment: `R.id.buttonNEXT` is of `int` type you can't use `setEnabled()` with it. See what others have posted.

Comment: @jackjay indeed indeed

Answer (score 0):

this is wrong

```
R.id.buttonNEXT.setEnabled(true);
```

**R.id.buttonNEXT** is the **id** (just an integer) that you have to use to create a Button

you should need to do something like

```
 Button myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonNEXT);
```

THEN after that you can invoke all the method a Buttom has

```
if (checked)
      myButton.setEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use it like this

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonNEXT); //casted to button. use the type is used
    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radioButtonYes:
            if (checked)
                b.setEnabled(true); //change to this
            break;
        case R.id.radioButtonNo:
            if (checked)
                b.setEnabled(true); //change to this
                break;
        case R.id.radioButtonDontknow:
            if (checked)
                b.setEnabled(true); //change to this
                break;
    }
```

Comment: although your answer is correct but to cast your view is good for safety.

Comment: So I should not have the view 'exposed' like I do in my code?

Comment: @DiegoFabiano actually you haven't find view in your code, what you have to do is first find your view by using id and then safely cast it to appropriate type and then use it.

Comment: @jackjay ok suggestion applied. But what you mean by safety?. I am curious please answer..:).

Comment: When you call `findViewById`, android doesn't know which kind of `View` it will find, so it always returns a `View` instance. You have to cast this view instance accordingly as `Button`, `TextView` etc. If you don't cast `Incompatible type error` is thrown. To avoid this you should cast explicitly. be on safer side.

Comment: @jackjay `Incompatible type error` does it always thrown? I didn't find that error when I used `findviewbyid` directly.

Comment: @CoDfather not always but for those classes which do not extend `View` class. Here in this `Button` class is extending  `View` class so no error . But its good to tell compiler which type of `View` you are expecting.

Comment: @jackjay `setEnabled()` is the method for views. So does it need always to be typecasted?

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19752026/why-this-type-casting)

Comment: @jackjay but it is only necessary if we need a desired view look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19752037/5962715)

Comment: Its completely right, But in the logical context when you use Button, its good to cast the view although you are using methods which are defined in `View` class.