# Android what is the need to cast return of findViewById()?

Tags: java, android, listview, casting

To get a **View** from XML in Android `findViewById()` is used let's say a **ListView**.

Due to the fact that `findViewById()` returns a parent **View** object rather than **ListView** object we need to cast the return of `findViewById()`

*ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);*

Output of `findViewById()` without casting:

```
System.out.println(findViewById(R.id.mainListView).getClass());     // class android.widget.ListView

System.out.println(findViewById(R.id.mainListView).getClass().getSimpleName());  // ListView

System.out.println((findViewById(R.id.mainListView) instanceof ListView));       // true
```

But indeed findViewById() is returning the **ListView** object then why it is neccessary to cast the return of `findViewById()` ?

Comment: Are you sure you need it in that particular case? From the docs: "Note: In most cases -- depending on compiler support -- the resulting view is automatically cast to the target class type. If the target class type is unconstrained, an explicit cast may be necessary." (The method is generic, and the type argument would be inferred by the type you're trying to assign to.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the result of findViewById(int id) because you're not casting an ListView object, your casting a View, of which ListView is only a specification.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19752066/2725502

Answer (score 0):

As a point, *findViewById* function return a view instead of it's sub view, i think you are confused return value and information get from *getClass*. The output of *findViewById(R.id.mainListView).getClass()* is *ListView* because view still have it's sub view's information, you can get it through the way.But actually *findViewById* return a value of View, so you have to casing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Jon Skeet in comments, findViewById(int id) method returns view(not subviews) in general, but this method is generic and can returns subviews if the compiler knows the type of target class, so in this case, casting is redundant, but in the case that, the type of target class is unconstrained, you have to cast explicitly.